# How do I escape m4 definitions in a string?

Tags: macros, escaping, m4

In my code, I have a certain register which I called "foo" using the m4 macros:

```
define(foo, w19)
```

Later on, I'm trying to print a string with the following format:

```
print: .string "The value of foo is %d\n"
```

Of course, my output is:

```
"The value of w19 is 5"
```

When I want my output to be:

```
"The value of foo is 5"
```

How do I escape the macro within this string?

Comment: @RossRidge Sorry, I messed up and put the output I'm trying to get rather than the output I got. The post has been fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

According to the first reference I found, and also the Wikipedia page on m4, expansion is suppressed by quoting, i.e.

```
`foo' is foo
```

Note that the opening and closing quote delimiters are backtick and apostrophe respectively.